# Figure caption within quote environment

Tags: floats, captions, indentation

In order to provide visual contrast, I have decided that I would like to have a certain section of a document I'm writing indented. To achieve this, I've simply been using the `quote` environment because that seems to be the simplest way of doing it.

The problem is that I would like to include some pictures in this subsection with captions. The problem is that if you use the `\caption` command, the caption is not indented:

[image]

It would seem trivial to correct this with a quick and dirty solution like the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]\addtocounter{figure}{1}

  \begin{center}

    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{assets/fig001.png}

    \begin{quote}Figure \thefigure: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\end{quote}

  \end{center}

\end{figure}
```

Where I've simply called the `quote` environment again, within the `figure` environment. But, for some reason, if you do this, the indentations aren't quite right and the captions are still indented by a slightly lesser amount than the rest of the text, as you can see:

[image]

The above was produced using the following MWE (the `lipsum` package was not used because I found the paragraphs were too long to screenshot):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
  commodo consequat.

  \begin{quote}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    ex ea commodo consequat.

    \begin{figure}[!ht]\addtocounter{figure}{1}

      \begin{center}

        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{assets/fig001.png}

        \begin{quote}Figure \thefigure: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.\end{quote}

      \end{center}

    \end{figure}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.

  \end{quote}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
  commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want to look at the `caption` package.

Comment: Looks good, I'll have a read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the default `quote` environment, the length `\rightmargin` is set to be the same as `\leftmargin` (from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)):

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

If you use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) you can force the width to be exactly (say) `\dimexpr\linewidth-\rightmargin-\leftmargin` giving you an output like

[image]

However, be careful, since floats may not end up where you put them in the text. With a float placement specifier of `[tb]` (instead of your `[!ht]`), the output resembles

[image]

which might not seem that ideal. Since you may not be interested in letting the image float, don't use a floating environment like `figure`, but rather a `center` environment with a manual `\captionof{figure}` (if you load `caption` or [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of)) set inside a fixed-width box of width `\linewidth`:

```
  \begin{center}

    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{assets/fig001.png}

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat}
    \end{minipage}

  \end{center}
```

Comment: The spacing between the "figure" and its caption does not seem to be equivalent to what is seen when using the `figure` environment. It might be because I am using a `tikzpicture` instead. I asked a question on how to solve this here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531220/how-to-achieve-standard-vertical-spacing-for-caption