# How to achieve standard vertical spacing for caption?

Tags: spacing, captions

I have the following MWE. In the the first `quote` environment, I would like the vertical spacing between the text and the caption immediately below it to be the same as the text and caption in the subsequent figure. How do I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \captionof{figure}{A caption}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two questions. 1) Why have you added `captionof` command in the `minipage` environment? 2) Why don't you also add the content for which you want to have the caption in the `minipage` environment? (In this case add `lipsum[1]` in the minipage environment.) My suggestion would be to remove the `minipage` if it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Niranjan I was just following the answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172915/figure-caption-within-quote-environment

Comment: The reason for putting \captionof inside a minipage is to avoid setting \@captype globally.  In this case, the center environment takes care of that for you.  
I might add that the center environment adds its own spacing, but probably not exactly the same spacing as \intextsep. Just how precise do you want it?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I would like it to mirror what would be seen for a regular `figure` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should behave precisely the same.  You might try throwing in an `\hrule` or two for more accuracy (MWE only).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\par\vskip\intextsep
\noindent\hskip-\leftmargin\vbox{\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{A caption}
}\par\vskip\intextsep
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

---

This fits the quote instead of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{quote}
\blindtext
\par\vskip\intextsep
\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{\blindtext}
}\par\vskip\intextsep
\end{quote}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{quote}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is pretty close! I am seeing a couple of things: 1) the tikz picture looks shifted slight to the right, i.e., not quite centred; 2) I can't get an MWE that replicates this, but I am seeing the caption text overflow into the margins.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to compensate for being inside the quote (\leftmargin).  Actually, \@totalleftmargin would be more accurate, but there is that pesky @!

Comment: This results in the tikzpicture being centred in the page, but also results in the caption not aligning with the quote text, i.e., the caption aligns with the regular page text. Sorry for back and forth, I am very appreciate of the effort!

Comment: The caption should always aligns with the page/column in a float.  That was the reason for using \vbox instead of a minipage or \parbox.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? I've added `tikzpicture`s for demonstration. (You can replace them with any figure of your choice.) There was no figure for the caption in your minipage. If you add one, you'll get the same vertical space in quote environment also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat}
\end{figure}
\begin{quote}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\captionof{figure}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{quote}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you, however it's not what I'm hoping to achieve. In this example, the vertical spacing between the tikz picture and the preceding paragraph is not the same as using a regular figure. Also, the spacing between the caption and the subsequent paragaph is not the same as when using the figure environment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. If you want to achieve this particular spacing by brute force, see my edit. `\vspace{\baselineskip}` adds the space of exactly one line :)